# Social Media - post from twitter to google+ (in 2017)

Tags: twitter, google-api, google-plus

i've searched on google but the posts are a bit out of date.  I was wondering how can i post to twitter and automatically posts to my google plus account.

so that no matter web or ios device i'll cross post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time there is no API which will allow for programmaticlly posting to the Google+ social-media website.